# PHP variable shortcut?

Tags: php, variables

Is there a shorter way to say this? 
In my header, I have this:

```
$white1 = '/~jonathan/www/index.php';
$white2 = '/';
echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

And here is how I am processing it:

```
<?php 
if (
(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $white1) 
or 
(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $white2)
) 
echo 'custom-class'; 
?>
```

I'd also like it to have a `$white3` and `$white4` that allow for `?lang=en`

Comment: This looks like a workaround for something. But if it's just about simpler code: a `switch` or a regex might help.

Comment: Try to avoid using PHP's closing tags `?>` at the end of a file. The PHP interpreter will do this automatically and it makes your application susceptible to spitting out unexpected whitespace (bad for web services).

Comment: Also -- I'd like to see more about what you're doing. This seems like a hacky routing system and I have a feeling there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: It's actually just for the nav.php. There are some pages that have a dark color scheme, so the nav elements have to be white or black. So, if it's a darker hero image, then I'm calling this `"custom-class"` as `color:white;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are a handful of options I want to match against, I like to use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) like this,

```
$options = array(
  '/',
  '/~jonathan/www/index.php',
);
if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $options)) {
  echo 'custom-class'
}
```

This method makes it easy to add to the list of `$options` without changing the payload or adding anything more than a single entry as needed. I like to keep the array sorted to make entries easy to find and keep it clean.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Matthew! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I answered the same thing first. too bad!

Comment: there are a lot of ways to write this, I like mine because it stacks vertically in case you end up with 10x options, which makes it easier to read in any editor and makes diff'ing cleaner vs. adding options to the same line

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], [$white1, $white2])) echo 'custom-class';
```

Of course you can define your array of matches before.

Comment: antoni, Matthew is right... yours is different. It didn't show me the array option laid out like that... Matthew's is so clean. Yours would make me have about 10 array options in a link. Something I was trying to avoid. Thank you, though!

Comment: no worries. And yes for sure you should write the array before. Remember you can also use the shorthand `[]` instead of `array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Put all variables in an array and check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is in the array.

```
<?php

$w = ['/~jonathan/www/index.php', '/'];
echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $w))
    echo 'custom-class';

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very close to what I was looking for, but Matthew's answer streamlined it just a bit more. Thanks!